# Angular2 WebStorm TS2304:can't find name 'EventSource'

Tags: angular, webstorm, server-sent-events, event-sourcing

I use WebStorm for Angular2/TypeScript development.

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('/interval-sse-observable');
```

But my problem is that the "EventSource" object is **unrecognized** (red underline, can't find name 'EventSource').

How to resolve it ?

Comment: can you add path for `EventSource.d.ts` in references.ts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003459/angular2-typescript-and-sse-eventsource or https://github.com/yankee42/typescript-server-sent-events/blob/master/sse.d.ts

Comment: @yurzui  as the second link , copy the **sse.d.ts** file ? where it should be put ?

Comment: Anywhere, i.e `ts` or `typings` folder.Then you should reference it

Comment: Another easy way is just write `declare var EventSource:any` before the using

Comment: @yurzui  i know , thanks !

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003459/angular2-typescript-and-sse-eventsource/45960164#45960164

Answer (score 1):

Please try this typescript version.

"typescript": "2.8.3"

`npm remove typescript // remove old version
npm install typescript`

and then try again